# spring integration dsl - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a flow with jpa gateway where I want to retrieve data and continue to another one. But I get an exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'estatement.move-to-cezar' available

**UPDATE**

Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class DocumentsController implements DocumentsApi {

    @Autowired
    public EstatementGateway estatementGateway;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<IdentityDTO> addDocument(@Valid @RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(estatementGateway.addDocument(requestDTO));
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteDocument(@PathVariable Long id) {
        estatementGateway.deleteDocument(id);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

Gateway

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface EstatementGateway {

    @Transactional
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "estatement.add-document")
    IdentityDTO addDocument(RequestDTO payload);

    @Transactional
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "estatement.delete-by-id")
    void deleteDocument(Long id);
}
```

estatement.delete-by-id flow

```
@Component
public class DeleteDocumentByIdFlowAdapter extends IntegrationFlowAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice exceptionProviderAdvice;

    @Override
    protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
        return from("estatement.delete-by-id")
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "estatement.delete-by-id")
                .handle(Jpa.retrievingGateway(this.entityManagerFactory).entityClass(Document.class).idExpression("payload"), c -> c.advice(exceptionProviderAdvice))
                .channel("estatement.move-to-cezar")
                ;
    }
}
```

estatement.move-to-cezar flow

```
@Component
public class MoveToCezarFlowAdapter extends IntegrationFlowAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Override
    protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
        return from("estatement.move-to-cezar")
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "estatement.move-to-cezar")
                .enrichHeaders(e -> e.headerExpression("docRef", "payload.docRef"))
                .handle(Jpa.updatingGateway(this.entityManagerFactory).persistMode(PersistMode.DELETE))
                .<Document, CezarMoveDTO>transform(p -> new CezarMoveDTO(p.getCezarViewUrl()))
                .channel("registry.move.cezar")
                ;
    }
}
```

clients configuration flows

```
@Configuration
public class ClientsIntegration {

    @Autowired
    private EstatementDocumentApi estatementDocumentApi;

    @Autowired
    private Pdf pdf;

    @Autowired
    private DocumentTempRestService documentTempRestService;

    @Autowired
    private DocumentRegistryRestService documentRegistryRestService;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow createEstatementEvidence() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("contract-evidence.estatement.create")
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "contract-evidence.estatement.create", Message::getPayload)
                .<EstatementRequestDTO>handle((p, h) -> estatementDocumentApi.createDocument(p).getBody())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow downloadPdf() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("pdf.download")
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "pdf.download", Message::getPayload)
                .<String>handle((p, h) -> pdf.download(p))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow registryMoveToCezar() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("registry.move.cezar")
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "registry.move.cezar", Message::getPayload)
                .handle(p -> {
                    CezarMoveDTO payload = (CezarMoveDTO) p.getPayload();
                    documentRegistryRestService.moveDocumentToCezar(p.getHeaders().get("docRef", String.class), payload);
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow registryUploadToTemp() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("registry.temp.create")
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "registry.temp.create", Message::getPayload)
                .<MultipartFile[]>handle((p, h) -> {
                    List<DocumentDetailDTO> result = documentTempRestService.uploadDocumentToTemp(p, 24).getBody();
                    return result.stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("docRef not found")).getDocRef();
                }).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow registryRemoveExpiration() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("registry.temp.remove-expiration")
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "registry.temp.remove-expiration", Message::getPayload)
                .<String>handle((p, h) -> documentTempRestService.deleteExpirationFromTemp(p))
                .get();
    }
}
```

stack trace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'estatement.move-to-cezar' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:46) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.getOutputChannel(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:173) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:205) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:188) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:360) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:271) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:188) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:143) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:135) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:481) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:433) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:424) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.java:65) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.deleteDocument(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.deleteDocument(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sk.cfh.document.estatementschedule.web.DocumentsController.deleteDocument(DocumentsController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:894) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:667) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

I noticed that when I simulate get entity `hanle(p -> new Document())` everything works correctly

```
@Override
protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
    return from("estatement.delete-by-id")
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "estatement.delete-by-id")
            //.handle(Jpa.retrievingGateway(this.entityManagerFactory).entityClass(Document.class).idExpression("payload"), c -> c.advice(exceptionProviderAdvice))
            .handle((p, h) -> {
                Document doc = new Document();
                doc.setId(1L);
                doc.setDocRef("XXXXXX");
                return doc;
            })
            .channel("estatement.move-to-cezar")
            ;
}
```

Comment: It shows an exception for the `deleteDocument` Gateway method, but you don’t. Please, come up with a simple configuration to reproduce

Comment: I added more info

Comment: Sorry, that still doesn’t show that `deleteDocument` and it is called from the MVC

Comment: I added gateway and controller

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Now that’s too much info to let me to reproduce here. Remember that I’m not going to deploy the whole JPA to play with it. I need really a simple code with clear reproduction. Thanks for understanding

Comment: OK! So your point is that when you replace a `Jpa.retrievingGateway()` with the plain `handle((p, h)` it start to work ?

Comment: How does it work if you remove `c -> c.advice(exceptionProviderAdvice)` ?

Comment: Yes, with plain handle it works. I pushed simple project to github https://github.com/bulalak/demo-spring-integration-jpa. Can you check please?

Comment: Please, tell, what is that without an `exceptionProviderAdvice`? And how does it look to let me to reproduce, please

Comment: without `exceptionProviderAdvice` it still does not work

Comment: Great! Thank you for the project! Now let me know what should I do with that to reproduce. Send request over HTTP, but with what content?

Comment: Oh! Sorry. You have shared at test-case. Cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you use somewhere an `@Autowired` for that your `estatement.move-to-cezar` `MessageChannel`. You need to declare bean for it separately to avoid such a conflict.

Also would be great to see how you use it for better understanding of the situation. And, please, share more stack trace.

**UPDATE**

I found the problem. It is indeed an internals of the `JpaBaseOutboundEndpointSpec`. I don't see a solution yet for the framework, but as a workaround I suggest you to declare a `estatement.move-to-cezar` `MessageChannel` bean, `@Autowired` it into that `DeleteDocumentByIdFlowAdapter` and don't use its name in the `channel()` definition already. Something like this:

```
@Component
public class DeleteDocumentByIdFlowAdapter extends IntegrationFlowAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice exceptionProviderAdvice;

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel moveToCezar;

    @Override
    protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
        return from("estatement.delete-by-id")
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "estatement.delete-by-id")
                .handle(Jpa.retrievingGateway(this.entityManagerFactory).entityClass(Document.class).idExpression("payload"), c -> c.advice(exceptionProviderAdvice))
                .channel(moveToCezar)
                ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I updated my question.

Comment: Please, take a look into an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Well, I have found the problem and that was a result of early bean initialization process. This has been fixed after moving SI Java DSL into the Core project since version `5.0`. So, that is also recommended to move there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: The fix is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/commit/afe8eac57a518f12020695c95995d757d4ba09c9. But I don't think that we have plans to release maintenance versions there...